# Forward prediction issue at Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I am training pt_MaskRCNN_coco_800_800_240G_3.0. Forward pass inside engine.py, which is

```
 loss_dict = model(images, targets)
```

has Keyerror 0.

Edited to

```
loss_dict = model([images], [targets])
```

Then another came out was

```
TypeError: conv2d() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (list, Parameter, NoneType, tuple, tuple, tuple, int), but expected one of:

 * (Tensor input, Tensor weight, Tensor bias, tuple of ints stride, tuple of ints padding, tuple of ints dilation, int groups)

   didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (list, Parameter, NoneType, tuple, tuple, tuple, int)

 * (Tensor input, Tensor weight, Tensor bias, tuple of ints stride, str padding, tuple of ints dilation, int groups)

   didn't match because some of the arguments have invalid types: (list, Parameter, NoneType, tuple, tuple, tuple, int)

> /opt/vitis_ai/conda/envs/vitis-ai-optimizer_pytorch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py(1130)_call_impl()

-> return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
```

I am using Vitist-AI version 3.

Pytorch 1.12.0

numpy 1.17.5

scipy 1.3.1